# Accessing items in rcarousel that are not visible

Tags: jquery

I have a rcarousel with 3 visible items, and I when one clicks and item, a class is removed from all items and added to the one that is clicked.  However, the only items that are in the DOM is the 3 that are visible.  So, if the one that has the class in not visible, and the user clicks another item, and you scroll back to the previous one, there are two that are selected.  How can I access the non-visible items to remove the class from those as well?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="seitemvideocarouselcontainer">

    <div id="ui-carousel-prev"></div>

<div class="seitemvideocarousel">

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="videothumbnail">
                <img class="seitemvideocarousel-90 selected" src="/images/library/videothumb/363303782_200.jpg" onclick="selectVideo(90)" title="Econom Recharge" alt="Econom Recharge">
            </div>
            <div class="videotitle">
                Econom Recharge 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="videothumbnail">
                <img class="seitemvideocarousel-84 " src="/images/library/videothumb/363159759_200.jpg" onclick="selectVideo(84)" title="Nalini Antares 12" alt="Nalini Antares 12">
            </div>
            <div class="videotitle">
                Nalini Antares 12 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="videothumbnail">
                <img class="seitemvideocarousel-2420 " src="/images/library/videothumb/5g8RYa1Aams.jpg" onclick="selectVideo(2420)" title="Mucka Blucka b" alt="Mucka Blucka b">
            </div>
            <div class="videotitle">
                Mucka Blucka b 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="videothumbnail">
                <img class="seitemvideocarousel-2438 " src="/images/library/videothumb/TTqpEJh03fI.jpg" onclick="selectVideo(2438)" title="I Uploaded This Video!" alt="I Uploaded This Video!">
            </div>
            <div class="videotitle">
                I Uploaded This Video! 
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

    <div id="ui-carousel-next"></div>
```

Here is the rcarousel call:

```
    $('.seitemvideocarousel').rcarousel({
        orientation: 'vertical'
    ,   visible: 3
    ,   width: 150
    ,   height: 120
    ,   start: onCarouselPageLoaded
    ,   pageLoaded: onCarouselPageLoaded
    });
```

Comment: I added my code, however I'm not sure how that will help.... I confirmed that any carousel item that is no visible is not in the DOM.

Comment: Can you access the hidden items though the DOM console? Try selecting them via $('.hidden-item'); and see if it prints out the same markup. If it does, you'll be able to manipulate it.

Comment: I can't quite see how you could access something that isn't there. jQuery traverses the DOM, so if it's not in the DOM, well... Presumably you have some code that removes/adds the items from the DOM when needed - so the proper classes should be set upon insertion. But maybe I've misunderstood something.

Comment: Yeah... the point was that rcarousel removes any items that aren't currently visible from the DOM and stores them internally, so obviously I can't remove a class from them with jQuery. I was just wondering if there was someone who has used rcarousel and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.event').on('click', function(e) {
     // Change this to selector or leave to remove class
     $(this).removeClass("class-to-remove');
});
```

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but that's a basic click event + remove class functionality.